# Row Correlation Heatmap Pandas

Tags: correlation, data-visualization, python, heatmap

I'm trying to find any relationship/patterns between a large number of rows in a dataset (~2000) and I'm thinking of using a correlation heatmap. However, after transforming the df using `df = df.T.corr()` and only plotting the first 100 rows with seaborn, it already starts to look unreadable:[image]

Is there a clearer way to do this with a larger number of rows?

Comment: Sorting the correlation matrix may provide clusters of variables, see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26920/1036) for one description of how to sort them.

Comment: Any Python based solutions?

Comment: I found `sns.clustermap(df.T.corr(), metric='correlation', method='centroid')` which might do the trick.

Comment: Try to do some basic clustering before (with the kernel trick if necessary), then order your dataset with respect to the classes. In python, use scikit-learn's k-means, PCA or whatever clustering technique works with your data.

Answer (score 2):

Answered in comments by Andy W:

> Sorting the correlation matrix may provide clusters of variables, see
> [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26920/1036) for one description of how to sort them